# getting error when run the `protractor` using chrome

Tags: google-chrome, protractor, angularjs-e2e

I ma trying to run the `protractor` using `chrome` but i am getting error as  :

```
protractor config.js
[15:54:58] I/launcher - Running 1 instances of WebDriver
[15:54:59] I/local - Starting selenium standalone server...
[15:55:01] I/local - Selenium standalone server started at http://172.18.32.112:51073/wd/hub
[15:56:06] E/launcher - chrome not reachable
  (Driver info: chromedriver=2.30.477700 (0057494ad8732195794a7b32078424f92a5fce41),platform=Windows NT 10.0.10240 x86_64) (WARNING: The server did not provide any stacktrace information)
Command duration or timeout: 60.51 seconds
Build info: version: '3.4.0', revision: 'unknown', time: 'unknown'
System info: host: 'INCHCMLP01756', ip: '172.18.32.112', os.name: 'Windows 10', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '10.0', java.version: '1.8.0_66'
Driver info: driver.version: ChromeDriver
```

how to fix this?
here is my config file :

```
exports.config = {
    framework : "jasmine",
    capabilities : {
        browserName : "chrome"
    },
    specs : ["spec.js"]
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: did u use directconnect = true?

Comment: Nope, in config?

Comment: Looks like an incompatibility issue. Can you mention your chrome version? Your chromedriver is fine- it's the latest one.

Comment: The version what I use is : `58.0.3029.110 (Official Build) (64-bit)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this? It worked for me with chrome version 58.

```
exports.config = {
    framework : "jasmine",
    capabilities : {
        browserName : "chrome", 
    },
    directConnect: true,
    chromeDriver: "C:/Path/to/chromedriver.exe",
    specs : ["spec.js"]
}
```

Comment: where would be my `chromeDriver` ? how to find the path?

Comment: you can make download here: [ChromeDriver](https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/index.html?path=2.30/) and save in your unit C or personal folder and copy the place for the `chromeDriver`